# Project Euler smallest multiple

Tags: java

The code seems to bee working for 10 but not the 20 as the question asks.
Maybe the number is too big when it is divisible by 20...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long c = 0;
    while(true){
        int x = 0;
        c++;
        for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++){
            x += c%i;
        }
        if(x==0){
            System.out.println(c);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

No error message, it just continues running without "process finished"

Comment: Please include in your question the problem statement you're attempting to solve.  Also, are you referring to the `i<=20` part when you say that it's not working for 20?

Comment: What do you mean by its working for 10? It will be an endless loop for 10 also as c will be 1 in the first iteration and x will keep on increasing unless its an overflow.

Comment: Your `x` will never be `0` when `i` is `20`.  The only time `x` is `0` is when you reset the value. Put `System.out.println("x: " + x + " i: " + i);` in your `for` loop and you'll see easily what is wrong.

Comment: @Abhishek Garg It actually does stop when `i` is 10 because `c` hits the number `2520` which is divisible by every single number between 0 and 10 therefore `x` remains at `0` the entire time for every `i`, ending the loop.  It is actually pretty hilarious that it manages to complete in that specific case.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically trying to find the LCM of 1-20 numbers. The LCM of that is 2,32,792,560. The program will eventually finish but will be very slow to do so.

Sample program to test.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        long c = 232792559;
        while (true) {
            int x = 0;
            c++;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                x += c % i;
            }
            if (x == 0) {
                System.out.println(c);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output of this will be 232792560